# What is the best way to ensure BINARY_PATH_NAME string quoted in C++ code

Tags: c++, windows, service, filepath

When you use the API CreateService to create a Windows service in C++, how can you ensure the BINARY_PATH_NAME string is double-quoted? If you use C#, this seems to be handled automatically by the base class. I am asking this question because a unquoted service path opens doors for hackers.

I have searched the net and could not find a satisfied answer. Of course I can check the service registry to make sure the string is quoted.

Comment: Check the first and last characters in the string to make sure it is a `"`?

Comment: @NathanOliver doesn't catch if a middle character is a " though, so it only half does the job.

Comment: Actually I am more curious if there is any Windows API to call for C++ since C# can handle this very gracefully.I do know what registry to check and update for a service.

Comment: Typically, you are generating the string yourself, so there's nothing to check; if your code puts in the quotes, they'll be there, otherwise they won't.  What is your scenario here?